# Generating an array of keyed arrays: More efficient way?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I want to sort an array of performers so that they are grouped by the first character of their first name. So for example 'A' in the following output, is for a collection of performers who's first name starts with 'A'.

```
[
"A"[Performer,Performer,Performer,Performer]
"B"[Performer,Performer,Performer]
"C"[Performer,Performer,Performer]
"D"[Performer,Performer,Performer]
"F"[Performer,Performer,Performer]
"M"[Performer,Performer,Performer]
... etc
]
```

I have achieved it but I'm hoping there is a more trivial way to do it. The following is how I achieved it.

```
class Performer {

    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let dateOfBirth: NSDate

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String, dateOfBirth: NSDate) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth
    }

}

private var keyedPerformers: [[String: [Performer]]]?

init() {
    super.init()
    let performers = generatePerformers()
    let sortedPerformers = performers.sort { $0.0.firstName < $0.1.firstName }
    keyedPerformers = generateKeyedPerformers(sortedPerformers)
}

//'sortedPerformers' param must be sorted alphabetically by first name
private func generateKeyedPerformers(sortedPerformers: [Performer]) -> [[String: [Performer]]] {
    var collectionKeyedPerformers = [[String: [Performer]]]()
    var keyedPerformers = [String: [Performer]]()
    var lastLetter: String?
    var collection = [Performer]()
    for performer in sortedPerformers {
        let letter = String(performer.firstName.characters.first!)
        if lastLetter == nil {
            lastLetter = letter
        }
        if letter == lastLetter {
            collection.append(performer)
        } else {
            keyedPerformers[lastLetter!] = collection
            collectionKeyedPerformers.append(keyedPerformers)
            keyedPerformers = [String: [Performer]]()
            collection = [Performer]()
        }
        lastLetter = letter
    }
    return collectionKeyedPerformers.sort { $0.0.keys.first! < $0.1.keys.first! }
}
```

Comment: Keyed Arrays? You mean a Dictionary of Arrays?

Comment: An array that contains dictionary's that contain arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, since you have an (sorted) array of section index titles it's not necessary to use an array of dictionaries. The most efficient way is to retrieve the array of `Performers` from the dictionary by key.

- Add a lazy instantiated variable `initialLetter` in the `Performer` class. I added also the `description` property to get a more descriptive string representation.

  ```
  class Performer : CustomStringConvertible{

    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let dateOfBirth: NSDate

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String, dateOfBirth: NSDate) {
      self.firstName = firstName
      self.lastName = lastName
      self.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth
    }

    lazy var initialLetter : String = {
      return self.firstName.substringToIndex(self.firstName.startIndex.successor())
    }()

    var description : String {
      return "\(firstName) \(lastName)"
    }
  ```
- To create the performers use an array rather than a simple string. The "missing" letters are already omitted.

  ```
  private let createIndexTitles = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
  ```
- The function to create the dummy instances pre-sorts the arrays of performers by `initialLetter` and then by `lastName`

  ```
  private func generatePerformers() -> [Performer] {
    var performers = [Performer]()
    for i in 0...99 {
      let x = i % createIndexTitles.count
      let letter = createIndexTitles[x]
      performers.append(Performer(firstName: "\(letter)", lastName: "Doe", dateOfBirth: NSDate()))
    }
    return performers.sort({ (p1, p2) -> Bool in
        if p1.initialLetter < p2.initialLetter { return true }
        return p1.lastName < p2.lastName
    })
  }
  ```
- Now create an empty array of strings for the section title indexes

  ```
  private var sectionIndexTitles = [String]()
  ```
- The function to create the keyed performers follows a simple algorithm : If the key for `initialLetter` doesn't exist, create it. Then append the performer to the array. At the end assign the sorted keys of the dictionary to `sectionIndexTitles`, the elements of the keyed arrays are already sorted.

  ```
  private func generateKeyedPerformers(sortedPerformers: [Performer]) -> [String: [Performer]] {
    var keyedPerformers = [String: [Performer]]()
    for performer in sortedPerformers {
      let letter = performer.initialLetter
      var keyedPerformer = keyedPerformers[letter]
      if keyedPerformer == nil {
        keyedPerformer = [Performer]()
      }
      keyedPerformer!.append(performer)
      keyedPerformers[letter] = keyedPerformer!
    }
    sectionIndexTitles = Array(keyedPerformers.keys).sort { $0 < $1 }
    return keyedPerformers
  }
  ```
- Now test it

  ```
  let performers = generatePerformers()
  let keyedPerformers = generateKeyedPerformers(performers)
  print(sectionIndexTitles , keyedPerformers)
  ```
- In the (presumably) table view use `sectionIndexTitles` as the section array and  get the performer arrays by key respectively.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time @vadian.

Comment: I should note here that I recently learned about the comparable protocol and how it can be used with 'sortInPlace' on an array of objects that implement it.